# First steps in mapbox

Tags: dataset, raster, mapbox-gl-js

Good morning, I have been researching the mapbox tool for a short time and I have some initial doubts. I would appreciate if you could guide me. You will find the first one very basic: with mapbox studio we only create the styles that we are going to use later in mapbox GL?
How do I publish a GL mapbox javascript code on a web page, is there a possibility to package it in an iframe?
What is the difference between Datasets and Tilesets? In the documentation I have read that from Datasets Studio you can only upload 5MB files, to upload larger files you have to convert them into Tilesets. I have also read that Tilesets are a kind of raster data.
Those are my first questions about mapbox. Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 0):

> With mapbox studio we only create the styles that we are going to use later in mapbox GL?

Yes - think of Mapbox Studio as "photoshop for maps" where you can design a map style for a variety of uses.

> How do I publish a GL mapbox javascript code on a web page, is there a possibility to package it in an iframe?

You can wrap your mapbox code in a script tag in your html doc for a simple implementation - [check out this demo](https://bl.ocks.org/samfader/c018fa1bcff38c3068b153e3d7e2ac6d).

It is also possible to package it in an iframe - [Mapbox Studio can generate that code for you](https://docs.mapbox.com/help/glossary/iframe/).

> What is the difference between Datasets and Tilesets?

A **[Dataset](https://docs.mapbox.com/studio-manual/reference/datasets/)** is a collection of geojson features that you can edit individually. This is often something like a defined set of points with additional data attributes that you've uploaded. You can plot points directly on a map canvas, but will quickly hit performance limitations.

A **[Tileset](https://docs.mapbox.com/help/glossary/tileset/)** is a collection of geojson, [raster](https://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/gentle_gis_introduction/raster_data.html), or [vector](https://support.esri.com/en/other-resources/gis-dictionary/term/7cbd3f7c-e17f-4bb0-a51a-318ccf5b68f1#:%7E:text=GIS%20Dictionary-,GIS%20Dictionary,as%20ordered%20lists%20of%20vertices.) data contained in a uniform grid of "tiles" that are optimized for production maps. It's how Mapbox can load the data around the viewpoint without needing to load the entire world at once. Mapbox Studio allows you to export datasets as tilesets for use in a map as a separate layer.